# Mysql2::Error Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, database-connection

I want run a rake db:migrate, but migrated are aborted and i see this error:

```
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
/home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.20/lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `connect'
/home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.20/lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `initialize'
/home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `new'
/home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `mysql2_connection'
/home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
/home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
/home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:913:in `initialize'
/home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `new'
/home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

if I run a server I will see this error page:

```
Mysql2::Error
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Extracted source (around line #70):       


     socket = socket.to_s unless socket.nil?

      connect user, pass, host, port, database, socket, flags #70line is this
    end

    def self.default_query_options
```

my database.yml file looks like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: hazzy93

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/dev.mysql2

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.mysql2

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.mysql2
```

Comment: are you able to connect to this db from coming line or some other tool using those credentials?

Comment: update your database.
  'database: "dev"' and not   'database: db/dev.mysql2'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: hazzy93
  host: localhost


test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: hazzy93
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: hazzy93
  host: localhost
```

Comment: still not working :/

Comment: You sure your username and password is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your database.yml
It should look like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306
  username: root
  password: hazzy93

development:
  <<: *default
  database: development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: production
```

You used the Syntax for sqlite3

Comment: not working :/ i have got still the same error

Comment: is your username and your password defently correct?